# Getting sum greater than $10$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I throw two dice until I get sum greater than $10$.

What are the odds that the number of throws will be less than $10$?
And what is odds that I'll get the sum of $12$ before $11$?

I was thinking for the first part the probability to get more than $10$ is $5,6$ and $6,5$.($2,6$)

And for the second part the chance to get $12$ is $\frac{1}{12}$.

Answer (score 1):

for the first question : you get sum $ \geq 10$ with permutations $(6,6)$,$(6,5)$,$(5,6)$, $(5,5)$ then the probability that sum $< 10$ in one throw is $\frac{32}{36}=\frac{8}{9}$.

Every throw is independent, so the probability that number of throws is less than 10 is equal to :

$$ \sum_{k=0}^8{(\frac{8}{9})^k \frac{1}{9} 
} =  1-(\frac{8}{9})^9 $$

for the second question you need to have, in the sequence of throws, the two dices sum to $11$ before they sum  to $12$, can you finish from here?

Comment: Nice! Small correction: the computed sum results in $1- (\frac{8}{9})^9$.

Comment: thanks, I fix it !

Comment: $5+5$ is not greater than $10$

Comment: So this is solution in case sum greater or equal than 10. That gives the OP something to think about for the case greater than 10 ;)

Comment: yes I think I read the description wrongly but I think it could be corrected easily by OP :)